# How do I properly append data to my collection using MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

So I have created a service that is going to connect to my database and grab a few proxies every here and there so it's going to be doing is contiguously, I am going to have to make it async or with a backgroundworker so it won't deadlock the UI.

However, I've gotten to the part where I've setup my relay command and I want to invoke that function that grabs the proxies.

I have created a service that has the function in it, I didnt add the connecting stuff etc yet so this is mostly hypothetical but the question still stands.

```
public class ProxyDeliveryService
    {
        public ProxyDeliveryService()
        {

        }

        public Proxy GrabProxy()
        {
            //Do work..

            //Return the proxy
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How do I append the data to my collection in my ViewModel with a good MVVM approach? No singletons or anything like that.
This here is throwing an error because it's expecting a delegate with a object parameter. `Action<object>` and a predicate so just like any other RelayCommand

```
public class ProxyContainerViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ProxyDeliveryService pds = new ProxyDeliveryService();
        public ObservableCollection<Proxy> Proxies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Proxy>();


        public RelayCommand Grabproxies { get; set; } = new RelayCommand(pds.GrabProxy(), true);

        public ProxyContainerViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the `Grabproxies` command supposed to *do* when invoked? Call `GrabProxy` and add it to the list? If so, why not just do that (in a named method probably)?

Comment: Wouldnt I have to access the collection from my `ViewModel` in my `Service` at that point? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: See my answer so we have a starting point to talk about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this. What's wrong with:

```
public ICommand Grabproxies { get; set; } = new RelayCommand(CreateProxy, true);


private void CreateProxy(object param)
{
    Proxies.Add(pds.GrabProxy());
}
```

Comment: I thought having functions inside the `ViewModel `like that was *taboo*

Comment: @MarkDenom I don't know where you got that idea but no. Not taboo at all. Heck, its pretty much the main point of `RelayCommand`. If you wanted a separate actor you should do a custom implementation of `ICommand` per usage

Comment: Okay so I guess I could have the GrabProxy function in there as well, but that would be taboo right? because it' s a service by itself, however `CreateProxy()` deals with providing the model to the view so I guess it's fitting

Comment: @MarkDenom Yeah, that sounds right. The VM doesn't know how to create proxies, but it can use the service to do so and add it to its own collection for whatever purpose

Comment: Okay yeah I got it then, it's fine as long as the function in the ViewModel goes hand in hand with the View sort of say

Comment: more or less, yeah.

Comment: What about the Predicate that it takes though, wouldnt I have to create another function that returns a bool?

Comment: @MarkDenom, are you talking about the "CanExecute" predicate? If so, this parameter is usally optional. If it is not (depending on your flavour of RelayCommand), you might try setting this predicate to `null`, which usually is indicating that the command can always execute. Unless of course you want/need to control when the command should be executable and when not...